# Issues with splitting a string and adding tabbed character

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.10.10

I'm trying to go through a bank statement string which contains seven elements in the order: date, description, reference number, transaction date, withdrawn amount, deposit amount, and closing balance. Description is the only part of the string where there's spaces, Rest of the elements do not have spaces of any kind.

There are around 3.5K lines in the text, and many of them have several issues like:

- random tabs in the description
- sometimes reference number does not have a tab before it
- sometimes I see two dates like `24/12/2021 24/12/2021 sample description REFNO123456 24/12/2021 0.00 100.00 1000.00`
- Many transactions do not have reference number, they are still split and tabbed correctly?

I've extracted this data from my own bank statement, which is copy protected and only one library worked and it exported it as .txt, so formatting it myself seems to be the only option. I'm painstakingly fixing the lines right now lol as even ChatGPT could not help with this, kept giving code which didn't work. Been a week and I've only gone through 1K lines. Any help would be appreciated.

example string: `24/12/2021 sample description REFNO123456 24/12/2021 0.00 100.00 1000.00`

```
f=open('/bankinfo final.txt','r')
txt=f.readlines()
cleanlist=[]
finalist=[]
for line in txt:
for x in line.split(sep=' '):
    if x!='':
        cleanlist.append(x)
    part1=(cleanlist[0])
    part2=(' '.join(cleanlist[1:-6]))
    part3=(' '.join(cleanlist[:-7:-1][::-1]))
    mashup=part1+'\t'+part2+'\t'.join(part3.split())
    finalist.append(mashup)
    mashup=''
    cleanlist=[]
f.close()
f=open('bankinfo parsed.txt','w')
f.write('\n'.join(finalist))
f.close()
```

Comment: Are all fields other than `description` dates or numbers?  Can a description ever have a naked date or number in it?

Comment: @AndrewRyan I'm trying to add tabbed characters between the seven columns I mentioned, so that I can open it as CSV. Unfortunately any example I copy will have a mix of names, their IDs, my card number, my name, company name, or merchants. The example I've mentioned is the closest I can provide.

Comment: @JonSG yes, two dates column, three amount columns and one reference column. Reference can sometimes have only numbers. But it is usually a mix of alphanumerics.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of regular expressions ([regex](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html#module-re)).  Be careful, many have entered the tombs of `regex` and not all have exited.

Any time you are working with parsing out strings and it is just a little bit complicated, you probably need to be working with `regex`.  You are using split with spaces, but the spaces aren't guaranteed to be consistent as you are observing, so it is time to do something different.  The below does most of what you want (I think) and demonstrates some of the key `regex` concepts of `findall()` and groups, which you can look at in the documentation.  It is also insanely handy to use [regex101](https://regex101.com) to check your work with regular expressions.

You didn't cover all of the possible configs in your problem description, so I made some assumptions:

- all transaction rows have all 3 (withdrawal, deposit, balance):  no blanks
- all transaction rows have at least 2 dates
- some rows have a REFNOxxxx with the key characters 'REFNO'
- the description could contain spaces, words, tabs, dates, REFNO's

Start with something like this and build out.  If you get stuck, post a new question showing what kinds of lines are giving you errors you are getting or what type of logic you need for a better re expression.  This is just a framework, you can work from here and assemble what you need to save the output or data frame it, etc.

##### DATA FILE (with tabs/spaces/trailing spaces/etc.):

```
24/12/2021 sample description REFNO123456 24/12/2021 0.00 100.00 1000.00
30/12/2022 some other       description     REFNO55 30/12/2022 1.25 2.34 500.00   
1/1/2023 REFNO44 2/2/2023 0.00 0.02 512.23
2/2/2022            Balance check       2/2/2022 0.00 0.00 643.29
3/3/2022 description with a date: 4/4/2022 3/3/2022 0.00 5.66 787.99
5/5/2022 description with (6.33) amount 5/5/2022 0.21 2.22 888.44
6/6/2022 description with refno cancel: REFNO123 REFNO124 6/7/2022 0.44 5.99 902.44
--end of transaction list--
```

##### CODE:

```
"""
read transactions
"""

import re

with open('txn_data.txt', 'r') as src:
    for line in src:
        line.strip()   # read a line and strip any trailing whitespace chars
        print('Analyzing: ', line)
        # find ALL of the dates in the line
        dates = re.findall(r'\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}', line)
        post_date = dates[0] if dates else None
        txn_date = dates[-1] if dates else None   # pick the last to avoid any date that might be in the description
        print(post_date, txn_date)

        # let's get the dollars
        # find 3 groups of digits, decimal, 2 digits separated by one or more whitespace chars
        amounts = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d{2})\s+(\d+\.\d{2})\s+(\d+\.\d{2})', line)
        if amounts:
            # print(amounts)
            withdrawal, deposit, balance = amounts[1], amounts[2], amounts[3]
            print(withdrawal, deposit, balance)
        else:
            withdrawal, deposit, balance = None, None, None


        # let's get the REFNO (if it exists)
        refnos = re.findall(r'REFNO\d+', line)
        refno = refnos[-1] if refnos else None  # get the LAST one in case there's one in description
        print(refno)
        if not all((post_date, txn_date, withdrawal, deposit, balance)):
            print('***** line not processed as a valid transaction!!')
        print()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
Analyzing:  24/12/2021 sample description REFNO123456 24/12/2021 0.00 100.00 1000.00

24/12/2021 24/12/2021
0.00 100.00 1000.00
REFNO123456

Analyzing:  30/12/2022 some other       description     REFNO55 30/12/2022 1.25 2.34 500.00   

30/12/2022 30/12/2022
1.25 2.34 500.00
REFNO55

Analyzing:  1/1/2023 REFNO44 2/2/2023 0.00 0.02 512.23

1/1/2023 2/2/2023
0.00 0.02 512.23
REFNO44

Analyzing:  2/2/2022            Balance check       2/2/2022 0.00 0.00 643.29

2/2/2022 2/2/2022
0.00 0.00 643.29
None

Analyzing:  3/3/2022 description with a date: 4/4/2022 3/3/2022 0.00 5.66 787.99

3/3/2022 3/3/2022
0.00 5.66 787.99
None

Analyzing:  5/5/2022 description with (6.33) amount 5/5/2022 0.21 2.22 888.44

5/5/2022 5/5/2022
0.21 2.22 888.44
None

Analyzing:  6/6/2022 description with refno cancel: REFNO123 REFNO124 6/7/2022 0.44 5.99 902.44

6/6/2022 6/7/2022
0.44 5.99 902.44
REFNO124

Analyzing:  --end of transaction list--
None None
None
***** line not processed as a valid transaction!!
```

Comment: Regex was the first thing that came to my mind, but I could not get them to work. I'll try your code, but to clear up the assumptions:
1. Yes. All rows have no blanks for 3 amounts, and two dates
2. ~90% rows have ref. nos., they start with any char/number. Some are just 6 digit long, some are 30 alphanumeric characters long.
3. The description contains a mix of names, their IDs, my card number, etc. It only has tabs if my code adds it, by default it does not have any tabs. It may have dates, but it is okay if they are lost in the process.